# Trying to connect to a .Net SOAP service using JAVA client

Tags: java, .net, wcf, soap, self-hosting

I try to connect to a .Net SOAP service, the SOAP service is made by another projectmember and is written in C#. He told me that he uses WCF Self Host Client.

I used netbeans 7.1 to generate the Java SOAP Client based on the WSDL. This worked when I tried it with java client to java server. But when I tried it with a .Net server I get:

```
    WARNING: SP0100: Policy assertion WARNING: SP0100: Policy assertion Assertion[com.sun.xml.ws.security.impl.policy.SpnegoContextToken] {
    assertion data {
        namespace = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy'
        prefix = 'sp'
        local name = 'SpnegoContextToken'
        value = 'null'
        optional = 'false'
        ignorable = 'false'
        attributes {
            name = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy:IncludeToken', value = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient'
        }
    }
    no parameters
    nested policy {
        namespace version = 'v1_5'
        id = 'null'
        name = 'null'
        vocabulary {
            1. entry = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy:RequireDerivedKeys'
        }
        assertion set {
            Assertion[com.sun.xml.ws.policy.sourcemodel.DefaultPolicyAssertionCreator$DefaultPolicyAssertion] {
                assertion data {
                    namespace = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy'
                    prefix = 'sp'
                    local name = 'RequireDerivedKeys'
                    value = 'null'
                    optional = 'false'
                    ignorable = 'false'
                    no attributes
                }
                no parameters
                no nested policy
            }
        }
    }
} is not supported under Token assertion.
```

I Read on other forums that this issue can't be fixed, does anyone know how to help me out?

For the server side we've set wsHttpBinding but we want to run out SOAP service without any security settings. Thats why we tried to fix it with this piece of xml in our app.config

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig">
      <security mode="None">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

It is just a basic self hosted WCF application.

Comment: Java client or .net client? Question and title appear contradictory to me

Comment: It's a Java client and a .Net server. Rewrote the question a bit to be more clear.

Comment: OK tis better now! What client side ws calling framework are you using? What server side security policy are you using? I would recommend downloading soapUI and attempting to call your service using that. Then once you have the extract XML you need to successfully call your service, you can attempt to get the java client to produce that XML.

Comment: I used netbeans to generate my client based on the WSDL, the webservice is generated by another projectmember, I'll ask him to post. But as far as I know he used default settings (security is not a concern for this project).

Comment: Would recommend calling it with soapUI. I am a Java guy myself so have never coded up a .NET server, only simple .NET clients to test my Java services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<endpoint address ="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ReparatieSysteem.WCFLibrary.IOrderListenerService">
```

We still had the endpoint binding set the wsHttpBinding, wsHttpBinding has several security features enabled but doesn't support the SpnegoToken (which the java client needed).

We've set it to basicHttpBinding because we don't need those security features.

Answer (score 0):

We are using wsHttpBinding but we want to do it without any security settings.
Thats why i tried to fix it with this piece of xml in our app.config

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig">
      <security mode="None">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

It is just a basic self hosted WCF application.